# grunt-contrib-watch + sass: how to specify the destination files?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have this workflow:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

    grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
        sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['src/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass']
    }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass"]);

};
```

After running `grunt watch` and change a `src/*.scss` file, I get this:

> > > File "src/main.scss" changed. Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
>
> Done, without errors. Completed in 0.949s at Tue Feb 02 2016 11:25:11
>   GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...

My problem: where is the generated file? how to specify the destination file?

I have also tried it using this workflow:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

    grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
        sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '.',
            ext: '.css'
          }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass']
    }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass"]);

};
```

and running also `grunt watch`, but when I change `src/*.scss` nothing happens..

**EDIT**: this is my grunt file after the answers:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

    grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
        sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.',
            src: ['src/**/*.scss'],
            dest: '.',
            ext: '.css'
          }]
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['src/**/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass']
    }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass"]);

};
```

Comment: Hey @ziiweb, did either of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `main.scss` file and that `@import`'s from `_sassfile.scss` in a `layout` folder. Sound good?

```
sass: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      outFile: 'dist/main.css.map'    // so you get a sourceMap file
    },
    dist: {
      files: {
        'dist/main.css' : 'src/main.scss'
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    files: ['src/layout/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass']
  }
```

This means `grunt watch` will monitor for changes in the *individual component* sass/scss files, then it will run the `sass` task, which will process everything out to `dist/main.css`.

If you are just using 1 Sass file, that is, `main.scss` is your only file, or if you're putting additional `_partial.scss` Sass files in the same directory, you can keep your watch command as

```
watch: {
    files: ['src/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass']
}
```

Last thing. The `cwd` for your Sass files, `src/` won't carry over to the `files` you specify for `watch`. So your Gruntfile was looking for file changes a directory above `src/` in the second workflow.

Comment: thanks!, now when I run `grunt watch` the changes on `*.scss` files (`main.scss`, `contact.scss`, `index.scss`) that I have at `src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass` are detected. The problem now is that the .css files generated are saved in the same path (`src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/main.css`, `src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/index.css`, `src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/contact.css` ), but I want to save them at `ẁeb/css/` folder, how can I do that? Note: I have pasted the new grunt file at my question.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! `dest: 'web/css/',` should move them to `base_directoy/web/css/` I'm here, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: thanks again, but I have added `dest: 'web/css/'` and the files are moved to `web/css/src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/main.css`, `web/css/src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/index.css` and `web/css/src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/contact.css` as `grunt -v watch` outputs, but since that path (`web/css/src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/`) doesn't exist, they are not really created.

Comment: Now I see. Add `flatten: true,` below `expand: true,` and this should tell Grunt to chop`src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/sass/` to `web/css/` when it exports css.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an output:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

  grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true
    },
    dist: {
      files: {
        //output added here
        'dist/main.css' : 'src/*.scss'
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    files: ['src/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass']
  }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ["sass"]);
};
```

> Note [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) should support all the [standard configuration options](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format) too.

With your original configuration, the task ran successfully but it didn't find any files to process. If I run with `grunt --debug --verbose` I get:

```
[D] Task source: /Users/edeustace/dev/github/edeustace/stack-overflow-questions/grunt-watch/node_modules/grunt-sass/tasks/sass.js

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
[D] Task source: /Users/edeustace/dev/github/edeustace/stack-overflow-questions/grunt-watch/node_modules/grunt-sass/tasks/sass.js
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
```

I guess you could consider this a bug in [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `grunt watch` is not firing in the 2nd grunt task configuration in your question is because of the wrong file path being watched.

```
watch: {
  files: ['*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass']
}
```

This only watches all the `.scss` files present in the root of the project (not inside any folder like **src**). You will need to set the `files` path for watch same as the 1st grunt task configuration in your question and it should work

```
watch: {
  files: ['src/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass']
}
```

**Note:** In case there are sub-folder under `src` folder containing `.scss` files, then you will have change the pattern to `src/**/*.scss` in watch's `files` array and to `src: ['**/*.scss']` in sass's `files` object

Also in the 2nd grunt configuration, the `files` object's `dest` option for sass task is set to `.`. This generates the CSS files at the root of the project. To generate them inside `src` or other folders, specify accordingly

You can check the working example at https://github.com/pra85/grunt-sass-example (Check the [subfolder](https://github.com/pra85/grunt-sass-example/tree/subfolder) branch for handling case of nested folders in `src` containing SASS files)